# How to program on this arm

Tags: embedded, arm, arduino

I have this samsung chip on a board (samsung s3c2510a) and I want to program to it via some method. However, I don't have a jtag reader on me and this board has a usb port. Is there any way to tell if I can program to the chip via this usb port? I ripped the board off a color laser printer by samsung and the board also has an ethernet connection.

Also, this board has 4 pins called "cn4 debug". Would this be of any use?

Here is a pic: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/262/img20120527120306.jpg/

Thanks,
Rohit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt programing this board would even be posible.  You could check if there is any software that is used to update the board (from the manufactuter) and try to reverse the protocol.  You would also need to figure out the format of the firmware file.  There is a lot of good stuff on hacking router firmware that may help.  You should be able to find some mailing list to ask for help on.

Answer (score 1):

For any device to be programmed over USB or indeed any port that is not part of the on-chip programming/debug architecture requires software/firmware supporting that port to be present on teh chip already.  Some microcontrollers include ROM based primary bootloader code for this purpose. The S2C2510A has no such bootloader.  But if the board already has software on it, part of it may indeed be a bootloader.  However unless you can get information on the protocol used, you do not really have much hope.

A picture of the board does not really help; what you need is a full data sheet and/or schematic.  You'll also want the data sheet and user reference manual for the chip itself.  You don't really have much hope of making sense of this board without them. The board does not look like a development board to me, so board specific information may not be available.

CN4 merely means "Connector Number 4".  Having just four pins it is likely that it is merely a connecting to the *Console UART* - a minimal low speed serial data peripheral on the S3C2510A.